# came/come to an end

Tags: verbs, tenses

I am writing a letter, but got confused with "come/came to an end". Here is my scenario.

Few years back I was working for a company then switch to another company. Right now I am writing a letter about it.

> My tenure at XYZ **came** to an end, when I decided to broaden my knowledge by working for ABC.

Is this statement correct?

Comment: You could avoid this by saying *My tenure at XYZ **ended** when I decided to broaden my knowledge by working for ABC.*

Comment: @cornbread ninja: Avoid what? If OP can't tell whether he should write *came* or *come*, why should he be any better able to decide between *ended* and *end*?

Comment: @FumbleFingers avoid down votes and close votes?  ;)

Comment: I do't know why I got a down vote. This forum is about asking questions. I am from non English speaking country. I had a doubt and asked it. If it bothers people then stay away.

Comment: Both mine and the other closevote are for General Reference. Which would still be the case if OP had asked whether to use *end/ended* instead of *come/came*. No disrespect to OP, but this is a very basic matter of verb tense, not imho suitable for ELU.

Comment: @ FumbleFingers, Actually initially I wrote it as suggested by "Cornbread". Then modified it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: basic matter for you, not for OP,huh?

Comment: @Noah: But ELU is [for linguists, etymologists, and *(serious)* English language enthusiasts](http://english.stackexchange.com/faq). I interpret *serious* there as meaning we expect questioners to at least have basic knowledge of using present/past tense verb forms.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Right. But I wonder where someone will ask these basic kind of questions.

Comment: @Noah: I can't believe you haven't noticed all the comments posted by RegDwight suggesting learners should sign up to the [english-as-a-second-language](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-as-a-second-language?referrer=NIy3I1OlXZ2EgMrV1X1RuQ2) site.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: isn't that still in Alpha?

Comment: @Noah: I've no idea. All I know is it'll never get off the ground if people keep diluting ELU by asking basic questions here that should be asked there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, 'came' is correct, as you are speaking in past tense.  Also, there should be no comma after 'end':

"My tenure at XYZ came to an end when I decided to broaden my knowledge by working for ABC."

Though this phrase is a bit of a mouthful, it is correct.